# Enumerate indices of returned api data

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

Im trying to enumerate the list of items that are output from the api via the function below.

//The function outputs
    "Prints => 
    Washington Capitals
    Main.js:52 New York Islanders
    Main.js:52 Pittsburgh Penguins
    Main.js:52 Carolina Hurricanes
    Main.js:52 Columbus Blue Jackets etc"

```
I want the function to output "Prints => 

Main.js:52 1:New York Islanders
Main.js:52 2:Pittsburgh Penguins
Main.js:52 3:Carolina Hurricanes
Main.js:52 4:Columbus Blue Jackets"



const url2 = ('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/standings');
        const response2 = await (fetch(url2));
        const data2 = await response2.json();
async componentDidMount() {
data2.records.map(function(element){
                element.teamRecords.map(function(element2){
                    const teamNames = element2.team.name;
                    console.log(teamNames)
            });

        });


    }

Prints => 

Main.js:52 New York Islanders
Main.js:52 Pittsburgh Penguins
Main.js:52 Carolina Hurricanes
Main.js:52 Columbus Blue Jackets
Main.js:52 Philadelphia Flyers
Main.js:52 New York Rangers
Main.js:52 New Jersey Devils
Main.js:52 Tampa Bay Lightning
Main.js:52 Boston Bruins
Main.js:52 Toronto Maple Leafs
Main.js:52 Montréal Canadiens
Main.js:52 Florida Panthers
Main.js:52 Buffalo Sabres
Main.js:52 Detroit Red Wings
Main.js:52 Ottawa Senators
Main.js:52 Nashville Predators
Main.js:52 Winnipeg Jets
Main.js:52 St. Louis Blues
Main.js:52 Dallas Stars
Main.js:52 Colorado Avalanche
Main.js:52 Chicago Blackhawks
Main.js:52 Minnesota Wild
Main.js:52 Calgary Flames
Main.js:52 San Jose Sharks
Main.js:52 Vegas Golden Knights
Main.js:52 Arizona Coyotes
Main.js:52 Vancouver Canucks
Main.js:52 Anaheim Ducks
Main.js:52 Edmonton Oilers
Main.js:52 Los Angeles Kings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide index in your map function

```
const url2 = ('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/standings');
        const response2 = await (fetch(url2));
        const data2 = await response2.json();
async componentDidMount() {
data2.records.map(function(element){
                element.teamRecords.map(function(element2, index){
                    const teamNames = element2.team.name;
                    console.log(`${index} : ${teamNames}`)
            });

        });


    }
```